# Why is the sin function from numpy plotting a straight plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is my code. I want to get a typical sine graph but somehow am not getting it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(0,2*(np.pi),(np.pi)/2)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y,color='b')
plt.show()
```

I am getting this graph.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XCBp.png)

Also, what would I need to modify to the axes so that it would look like this ?
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYYC3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the step size in your range:

```
x=np.arange(0,2*(np.pi),(np.pi)/2)
```

You're evaluating `sin` every pi/2 ... in other words, only at -1, 0 and 1.
You need a *much* smaller step size ... say, `np.pi / 100`

For future problems, see this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  Simply printing `x` would have shown your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that. Can you also tell me how would I move the axis to match the second image attached ? Thanks again!

Comment: Look in the `matplotlib` documentation for the `origin` and `extent` keyword arguments.